# Could not Update data using asp mvc Entity-Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

As a beginner with ASP .net MVC i m trying to update database using Entity Framework but the id is always null what it make the modelstate always non Valide 
 this is Code of the Controller

[image]

Comment: You need to include the code in the question, not an image of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Id` is equal to null because the model binder doesn't find a value from your posted data.

To solve this you must add the `Id` as a hidden field into your view. In your Edit.cshtml just add the following line :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Comment: It is always null :/

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this ->

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Field1,Field2,Field3...")] Etudiant et)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(et).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```